# Is double disk storage required in JFrog Artifactory for two files with the same MD5 value?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-pipelines

For instance, I uploaded FILE1 to Artifactory PATH1. Then, I upload FILE1 (the same file) to Artifacotry PATH2 (a different path).

Will these two shares the same disk storage as they have the same md5 value?

I hope Artifactory could treat them as the same file to save the disk storage. Something like only save the orginal file on disk and mantain a number of reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory uses [Checksum-Based Storage](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/checksum-based-storage) to store files based on their SHA1 checksum. So each file is stored only once in the filestore but may have several references in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Deploy the file by checksum](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-rest-apis/deploy-artifact-by-checksum) instead of uploading it fully a second time.

Something like this should work:

```bash
curl ${repository}/${newPath} -X PUT -H X-Checksum-Deploy:true -H X-Checksum-Sha1:${sha1checksum} -H Content-Length:0
```

You can either add the credentials to `curl` manually (e.g. `-u ...:...`), or get the JFrog CLI do it for you if you're using it (`jf rt curl ...` should manage that for you).

This only seems to work for SHA-1 or SHA-256, but I'm assuming if you're able to compute the MD5 checksum of your initial file, you should be able to compute the SHA-1/SHA-256 quite easily too.

I'm not sure how it works if you *actually* upload the file a second time, but I would assume it saves space internally by comparing their checksums indeed. (This may also depend on [some checksum policy settings](https://jfrog.com/help/r/what-are-client-checksum-server-checksum-and-checksum-policy-in-local-repositories/what-are-client-checksum-server-checksum-and-checksum-policy-in-local-repositories).)

Comment: As @Hanan said in the other answer, it does indeed seem to use checksums internally